# use openAI CLIP with torch tensor or numpy array as input

Tags: python, pytorch, openai-clip

How to use a pytorch tensor or an openCV iamge correctly as input for for OpenAi CLIP?

I tried the following but this didn't work so far :

```
device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
clip_model, clip_preprocess = clip.load("ViT-B/32", device=device)
clip_preprocess(torch.from_numpy(OpenCVImage)).unsqueeze(0).to(device)
```

- the preprocess step fails with message `Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)`
- openCVImage is a object that was already processed with cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB

Comment: "opencv images" are numpy arrays. this is not an OpenCV issue. I have removed the tag. -- may I also recommend that you take the [tour]? you don't seem to have accepted any answers on any of your questions so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the transforms code for `CLIP`, it shows that you need a PIL Image Object not a Numpy Array or Torch Tensor. [These lines](https://github.com/openai/CLIP/blob/main/clip/clip.py#L79)

```
def _transform(n_px):
    return Compose([
        Resize(n_px, interpolation=BICUBIC),
        CenterCrop(n_px),
        _convert_image_to_rgb,
        ToTensor(),
        Normalize((0.48145466, 0.4578275, 0.40821073), (0.26862954, 0.26130258, 0.27577711)),
    ])
```

In PyTorch, mostly Transforms are written for PIL not for Numpy or Torch due to performance and good results. So you have to convert each Image to PIL first via

```
image = Image.fromarray(np_img)
```

or you can simply use the last transform manually like

```
my_transform = Compose([
        ToTensor(),
        Normalize((0.48145466, 0.4578275, 0.40821073), (0.26862954, 0.26130258, 0.27577711)),
])
# Use it on np image now

my_transform(torch.from_numpy(OpenCVImage)).unsqueeze(0).to(device)
```

Comment: thanks, that's exactly how I fixed this,
although not sure if the transforms are really made only for the PIL images

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a system-related issue (the `SIGKILL` interrupt).
What system are you using? What OS? What type of `device`? Is it possible you exceeded CPU/GPU memory limit?

Comment: I am using wsl-2 with cpu, 
with a PIL image everything works fine, so I am thinking maybe something is wrong with my code

Comment: @werberbang what is the size of the image, in `PIL` and in `openCV`?

Comment: with PIL it works fine on any images I have locally, 

the image I get from OpenCV that I feed to CLIP is 376*297*3